# Apache Hadoop: Insert compress data into HDFS

Tags: compression, text-files, hdfs, hdfstore

I need to upload 100 text files into HDFS to do some data transformation with Apache Pig.

In you opinion, what is the best option:

a) Compress all the text files and upload only one file,

b) Load all the text files individually?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends - on your files size, cluster parameters and processing methods.

If your text files are comparable in size with HDFS block size (i.e. block size = 256 MB, file size = 200 MB), it makes sense to load them as is.

If your text files are very small, there would be typical HDFS & small files problem - each file will occupy 1 hdfs block (not physically), so NameNode (which handles metadata) will suffer some overhead on managing lot of blocks. To solve this you could either merge your files into single one, use hadoop archives (HAR) or some custom file format (Sequence Files for example).

If custom format is used, you will have to do extra work with processing - it will be required to use custom input formats.

In my opinion, 100 is not that much to significantly affect NameNode performance, so both options seem to be viable.